# Chrome redraws background image

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, jsf, background-image

The [site](http://service-infosearch.rhcloud.com/) pages contains the same background image and if we check ChromeDevTools it shows that the background image comes from cache, but every time screen clears, so we are getting the effect of flashing in Chrome (actually it's Iron). In contrast, Firefox has no such behaviour, it does't redraw the cahed image every time. 
Is it normal behaviour for Chrome?

```
body {
    background-image: url(#{resource['images:fon.png']});
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: could you post some relevant code so we can test it?

Comment: I think that the flashing cames from the time spent on loading the css file and other resources. Have you tried to put the above css in an inline statement?

Comment: @user3845133 then why flashing does't came in firefox and opera?

Comment: different caching/rendering mechanism, I suppose...For example if you have missing images firefox will fire load event instantly after all other resources are loaded, but in Chrome you will have to wait a bit before firing the event.  Did you check if the css is also cached?

Comment: @user3845133 css is reloading every time (Status Code:304 Not Modified)

Comment: => just try to move the above declaration in a style tag and write down the results.

Comment: @user3845133 now body tag looks like `<body style="background-image: url(/WEBSearchPrime_JB/faces/javax.faces.resource/fon.png?ln=images);">` and background still flashing

Comment: the last idea I have is to move the background as img tag inside the body and style it with css to look like a bg.

Comment: @user3845133 well, to be honest I don't think that will be a solution. I have testted Safari and it flashing too. So I think it's a core browser issue...